# Typescript inferring union type instead of specified type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

I want to embed "metadata" into a type for use in creating a type-safe REST client. The idea is to use the type metadata in the link to infer the correct endpoint schema for use in the API call. E.g.

```
type Schema = {
  users: {
    GET: {
      query: { userId: string };
    };
  };
  posts: {
    POST: {};
  };
};

type User = {
  self: Link<"users">;
};

const user: User = { self: "https://..." };

http(user.self, "GET", { userId: 1 });
```

I was able to get this working with brute-force conditional types.

E.g.

```js
type Routes = "users" | "posts";
type Verbs<R> = R extends "users" ? "GET" : never;
type Query<R, V> = R extends "users"
  ? V extends "GET"
    ? { queryId: string }
    : never
  : never;
```

But this results in a normalized type model that would be difficult to enter manually. Instead I want to use a de-normalized type E.g.

```js
type Schema = {
  users: {
    GET: {
      query: { userId: string };
    };
  };
  posts: {
    POST: {};
  };
};
```

Using types like this:

```js
type Query<
  S,
  RN extends keyof S,
  VN extends keyof S[RN]
> = OpQuery<S[RN][VN]>;
```

I am able to get most of this working with the exception of the final and critical bit, inferring the route name from the link type:

```js
type Schema = {
  users: {
    GET: {
      query: { userId: string };
    };
  };
  posts: {
    POST: {};
  };
};

type Link<R extends keyof Schema> = string;

type LinkRouteName<L> = L extends Link<infer R> ? R : never;

type name = LinkRouteName<Link<"users">>;
```

expected: name === "users"

actual: name === "users" | "posts"

Comment: `type Link<R extends keyof Schema> = string;` doesn't do anything with `R`, so I'm confused.  Are you trying to get a [branded primitive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) so that the compiler remembers that the string somehow "means" a `"users"` call as opposed to a `"posts"` one?

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4FgBQUUArgM4QBOpAXDlAOICiAKrdlAI7GUhsnkUAkgBNapYBQCWAOwDmUAL4BuRSuUEiYAPbiadAAoB5GKxzLVBdflCQoAGRkBrADwwoEAB7AI04aSiOECBaAGawiCioAHyYUOJSclAAZHQA+qmkEWgA-LRuCgTCEHAANqgU0CHE0nDAklrSUAjAwGDOGrDuXj5+AUGh4UhoADQdAGpd3r7+gcFh8EOoANowALqjhFBRABQdRMQUJbQO0i4wURtERABulABGtGOXVwB0b0tcPKt5WctrS2NVpMev52J8KLwoDIQpQoABFRRQbJQJZwoG0JarDoASlo1y0kmESgINmgAFUBLFsOQSiFjk5nAAiMiUUiMqJWOANcT8Si0CmwrDsGl0qCM5qtGgAeilbxejIs+AlYG2LIoLxFwzFTGYjK17DVIlojIAjAqFNjidZwNB9DpgFSRfTTkztLp2QV8FzpDy3cBaHaeUK4hBacbldLZW9zQRlds-RrQyEtYyjCZGZagA)?

Comment: @jcalz yes that is correct, although it is less about branding and more about the type metadata. "R" does nothing for the Link type it is simply metadata that communicates that this Link points to a particular route. We can use that type metadata to provide a type-safe list of verbs, query parameters, and body for that route endpoint.

Comment: @jcalz taking a look at your example, it appears you are getting the correct infer. Trying to map back to my solution to confirm this is working.

Comment: @jcalz Ok, I see. The issue was that Typescript was treating my Link type as a string regardless of the type information I was declaring it with. But by "&" the type system now respects the fact that "R" has some significance and the type is more than just a string. Nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and not nominal, meaning that it is the *shape* of a type that determines its identity, not the *name* of the type.  A type alias like

```
type Link<R extends keyof Schema> = string
```

doesn't define a type that depends on `R` in any way.   Both `Link<"users">` and `Link<"posts">` evaluate to `string`; they are just different names for the same type, and thus don't make a difference to the type system.  In theory the two types are indistinguishable from each other... there are cases when the compiler *may* distinguish two identically shaped types like this different names, but you shouldn't ever rely on this.

Anyway, the information from the `R` type is thrown out, and the following can't bring it back:

```
type LinkRouteName<L> = L extends Link<infer R> ? R : never;
```

Both `LinkRouteName<Link<"users">>` and `LinkRouteName<Link<"posts">>` are evaluated to `LinkRoutName<string>`, from which nothing more definite can be determined past the generic constraint on `R` in the `Link<R>` definition: that is, `keyof Schema`, a.k.a. `"users" | "posts"`.  The TypeScript FAQ has a [similar example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) where type inference is unable to bring back discarded type information.

---

So, if you want two types to be treated differently, they should have different structures.  If `Link<R>` were an object type, I'd suggest adding a property to that object called, say, `name`, with a value of type `R`.

But you are just using the primitive `string` type.  Getting a primitive type to differ structurally is not really possible at runtime (you can't add properties to it like (`var a = ""; a.prop = 0;`)).  You *could* use the [`String` wrapper type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) and add properties to that if you want.

Another way to go is to just mislead the compiler into treating a primitive `string` typed value as if it differed structurally from just `string`, by using something called "[branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)".  You intersect the primitive type with a phantom "brand" property to be used to distinguish the type.  My suggestion here would be:

```
type Link<S extends keyof Schema> = string & { __schema?: S };
```

The phantom property is optional, so you will be allowed to write

```
const userLink: Link<"users"> = "anyStringYouWant";
```

without a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), but you have to make sure to manually annotate the type.  The following won't work:

```
const userLink = "anyStringYouWant";
```

That will just be a `string` and not a `Link<"users">`.

---

Once you have that, the rest of it should fall into place.  A possible declaration for the `http()` function could be:

```
declare function http<
  S extends keyof Schema,
  V extends keyof Schema[S],
  >(
    url: Link<S>,
    verb: V,
    ...[query]: Schema[S][V] extends { query: infer Q } ? [Q] : []
  ): void;
```

which uses [rest tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to represent that `http()` may or may not take a third parameter depending on whether or not the corresponding `Schema` entry has a relevant `query` property.

Let's verify that this works:

```
type User = { self: Link<"users"> };
const user: User = { self: "https://..." };
http(user.self, "GET", { userId: "1" }); // okay
http(user.self, "GET", {}); // error!  userId missing
http(user.self, "GET"); // error! expected 3 arguments

type Post = { self: Link<"posts"> }
const post: Post = { self: "https://..." }
http(post.self, "POST"); // okay 
http(post.self, "POST", { userId: "1" }); // error! expected 2 arguments
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4FgBQUUArgM4QBOpAXDlAOICiAKrdlAI7GUhsnkUAkgBNapYBQCWAOwDmUAL4BuRSuUEiYAPbiadAAoB5GKxzLVBdfgKhIUADIyA1gB4YUCAA9gEacNJQThAgWgBmsIgoqAB8mFDiUnJQAGR0APpppJFoAPy07goEBMIQcAA2qBTQocTScMCSWtJQCMDAYC4asB7evv6BwWERSGgANF0Aaj0+fgFBIeHwI6gA2jAAuuOEUNEAFF1ExBRltI7SrjDRW0REAG6UAEa0E9c3AHQfK1w86-nZqxsVhN1tM+gF2N8KLwoDJQpQoABFRRQHJQFYIkG0FbrLoASloty0kmESiK+Fs0AAqgI4uxyGVQqdnC4AERkSikFmxKxwJrifiUWjU+FYOkQBm0Fmtdo0AD0so+bxZFnw0rAu3ZFDe9NCoygLKYzBZevYmpEkoAjMqFLiVPKoFonKgQAQ1RqBNrxbr9YbjWZbVB7ZQKFoKABCQ4CERQZCSUikGSyV1tdWaz0MvUGlgsgNBigh8M9SD1CDCKAAZiglVkxGQvmApDJFKg+h0wFp8S9TPOrO0ui5igIvOk-L7wForf5os7Ev1arlCo+1uT7V2Y-T3pZRhMObtsodTpAUBX6vXOsz26NJoFQlE+qtilz++DoYjXmLPjLACYqxQa3XpAbAggA)

Comment: Worked like a charm and thank you for the great background info.