# Typescript - using "infer" keyword on generic type with multiple multiple generic parameters not working as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have following type:

```
type Foo<A, B> = A & B;
```

When I do this:

```
type Bar<T> = T extends Foo<infer _, infer K> ? K : never;
```

I expect that this would work:

```
const someVariable: Bar<Foo<string, number>> = 200;
```

But I am getting the following error: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Comment: Unable to reproduce [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAQQDRQEID4oF4rJQA+mA3ALABQVokmAhgE6IAqO+LUEAHsBAHYATAM6wEiAJb8AZhEZQA+uimz5AaRwB+KGqgAuKPwgA3ORWqUAxnH7DgUYXAC2EAGpMJ9AEYAbCAYwmRHgkO0YpAHN0fgBXJy85LHYoACYABjTSIA)

Comment: Updated but I think you pointed me in right direction nevertheles. (I changed type Foo)

Comment: Hmm, there's no obvious way to predict what kind of inference you're going to get from this. If I tell you that I added two positive numbers together to get 10, there's no way for you to accurately infer what my first number was.  The information just isn't present.  Saying that `X | Y` is equivalent to `A | B` doesn't guarantee that `X` is `A` and `Y` is `B`. It could easily be that `X` is `B` and `Y` is `A`, or `X` is `A | B` and `Y` is `never`, or just about anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58696848/2887218

Comment: Oh, you edited to intersections.  This is arguably worse `string & number` is `never`.  It's like saying I multiplied two numbers together to get 0 and asking you to figure out what the first one way.  It could literally be anything.  Again, "`X & Y`  is `A & B`" doesn't imply  "`X` is `A` and `Y` is `B`". It could be "`X` is `A & B` and `Y` is also `A & B`" or just about anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Foo<A, B> = A & B;
```

be careful with passing primitive like `string` and `number` because

```
type Foo<A, B> = A & B;
type R = Foo<string, boolean>;
R is never
```

Probably you should change to  `type Foo<A, B> = A | B;` it should solve your issue.

Comment: Ah, looking this with fresh morning brain makes absolutely sense. For some reason I thought if I have 
`type Bar<T> = T extends Foo<infer _, infer K> ? K : never;`
typescript would not care what result of `Foo<infer _, infer K>` rather only about what inferred `K` to create such type was but obviously that would be problematic for number of reasons if it were that way.